# Attachment VF page

Tags: visualforce, attachment, stylesheets

I am putting together VF page to render attachments, it will reside in service console so I was trying to get styling roughly aligned with other related list components. However when I set the `showheader=false` then the links to open the attachments dont function, they display different javascript link.

anyone else have similar issue??

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="AttachmentController" standardStylesheets="false" >


<h3> <font align="left" style="'SalesforceSans-Light',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#16325c; font-weight:normal;" >Email Attachments</font></h3>
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!attachedFiles}" var="att">

      <apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">File Name</apex:facet> 
    <apex:outputLink value="/{!att.Id}" target="_blank">{!att.Name}</apex:outputLink>
     </apex:column >
     <apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">File Link</apex:facet> 
     <apex:outputLink value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!att.Id}" target="_blank">Download File</apex:outputLink>
     </apex:column >

  </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock >
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What is displayed with the attribute `showheader=false`?

Comment: when I change that then the page styling looks similar to console component. it renders links in blue like typical html a href

Comment: This is due to your attribute:  `standardStylesheets="false"` which removes all the Salesforce styling.

Comment: I thought that too but whether its there or not page renders the same, only removing the showheader seems to impact how it displays

Comment: There's no link between the style of the link and why they are not working. What's the url opened by the no working link?

Comment: its attachment link /servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!att.Id}